# Conditional compilation depending on sizeof(double)

Tags: arduino-ide, compile, data-type

Is there a macro (#define ...) somewhere in the bowels of Arduino IDE or core header files which tells me at compile time(!), if the `double` data type for a given platform/board is a true double precision floating point number (64 bit width) or "only" an alias for a single precision float (32 bit width)?

With Arduino, both can be the case. 8-bit AVR boards have `double` equal to `float`, ARM-based boards (like Arduino Zero) support "true" double precision.

I am working on a library which implements some bit-banging of floating point numbers (both single and double precision). Due to the low-level nature of the problem, there must be separate functions for `float` and `double`. I would like to do somthing like that:

```
uint32_t function_for_float(float f) {
    // function body here...
}

#if defined(HAS_64_BIT_DOUBLE)
uint64_t function_for_double(double d) {
    // function body here...
}
#endif
```

That way, a compile time error would be generated if somebody tried to use the "double" version on platforms which do not support the "true" double data type. I *want* the compiler error to be generated, because `function_for_double()` will do silently "the wrong thing" when fed a single precision float, leading potentially to difficult-to-debug problems.

Right now, I am defining a macro constant for every relevant board I own, like this:

```
#if defined(ARDUINO_SAMD_ZERO) \
 || defined(SAMD_FEATHER_M0_EXPRESS) \
 || defined(ADAFRUIT_FEATHER_M4_EXPRESS)
    #define HAS_64_BIT_DOUBLE
#endif
```

But this is ugly and not future-proof (new boards can/will become available...).

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is not really an Arduino question. Arduino uses g++ to compile, so your question really is "can g++ do this?" Judging by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079243/how-can-i-use-sizeof-in-a-preprocessor-macro) - not really. You can assert if double isn't 8 bytes (I tested that) but not make a choice, unless there is another tricky way of doing it.

Comment: @NickGammon: Thanks for the link. I actually have a `static_assert(sizeof(double) == 8)` in the code of my "double function". However, then the complete library .cpp file will not compile on platforms where `double` ist only four bytes. This is what brought me to think about conditional complilation in the first place. I would like to generate a compiler error only if sombody tries to *use* the double version when he/she shouldn't. Somewhere in Arduino there surely must be definied that double is equal to float? I hope(d) to use this as a hook somehow...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `double` data type is almost universally 8-bytes long, so you could
simply

```c
#if !__AVR__
# define HAS_64_BIT_DOUBLE
#endif
```

Gcc provides a more specific macro though: `__SIZEOF_DOUBLE__`, which
has the same value as `sizeof(double)`. But I do not know whether it is
provided by other compilers.

Comment: Perfect! I will make use macros `__SIZEOF_DOUBLE__` and `__SIZEOF_DOUBLE__`, even if they are gcc/g++ specific. The Arduino IDE uses g++ as its backend, anyway, so this is "good enough" for me.

Comment: Just verified that `__SIZEOF_DOUBLE__ == 4` on an Arduino Pro Mini (AVR 328p) and `__SIZEOF_DOUBLE__ == 8` on an Adafruit Feather M0 (ARM Cortex-M0+ / SAMD21). Thanks a lot! I have selected your answer as the correct one.